# Flask: return error code 401.x

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to notify my client that there was a login failure by returning the error code `401.1` from my Flask based REST API.

Flask is fine with something like this:

```
return {"message": "Invalid username or password"}, 401
```

How do I return a HTTP `401.1` instead of a `401`?

Comment: 401.1 is a Microsoft extension; the official HTTP RFCs don't allow for such extensions and it'll depend on your WSGI stack if this can be propagated at all. Why do you need to send this from Flask?

Comment: From the [most recent HTTP RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.2): *The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you. The error code was mentioned in a client requirement.

Comment: I've stated so in my answer, but I'm re-iterating it here: please check with your client what they want, *really*. Setting a status code to 401.1 would break RFCs and your server would be the only one doing this. The IIS 401.1 status code is *not a HTTP status code*, only an internal code to send to the logs and to make it easier to provide custom error messages to any human reading the response message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't out of the box. The Werkzeug response object used in the Flask stack will always treat the status code as an integer.

That's because the HTTP RFCs are [very clear on what values are permitted for a status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2):

> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the
> result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's
> corresponding request.

Please **tripple-check** your requirements with your client before you go break the RFC.

The addition of a `.x` sub-status number is a [Microsoft IIS extension](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis) that is used *only internally to the server*. The server sends a 401 status, but logs a detail substatus code in the logs and lets you vary the custom error message based on the sub-code. So the *end user* sees `401.1 Logon failed` in the error page served, but the status line is still set to `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`. See [this post by a Microsoft engineer](https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/sending-status-as-401-1.73739/#post-362357):

> Please note that there is no such thing as a 401.1 when it comes to the HTTP
> headers themselves. (Watch using a network sniffer to confirm for
> yourself).
>
> When you see a 401.1 in IE, what's really happening is that IIS is sending
> down a HTTP/401 error code in that HTTP Result, but the body text provides
> the additional information you're seeing that claims it's really a 401.1

If you *absolutely must* send such a status (and break RFC compliance), you'd have to subclass the `Response` class used by Flask:

```
from flask import Response
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES

class ResponseWithSubstatus(Response):
    @property
    def status_code(self):
        """The HTTP Status code as number"""
        return self._status_code

    @status_code.setter
    def status_code(self, code):
        self._status_code = code
        try:
            main_code = code
            if isinstance(code, str) and '.' in code:
                main_code = int(code.partition('.')[0])
            self._status = '%s %s' % (code,    
                HTTP_STATUS_CODES[main_code].upper())
        except (ValueError, KeyError):
            self._status = '%s UNKNOWN' % code

    @property
    def status(self):
        """The HTTP Status code"""
        return self._status

    @status.setter
    def status(self, value):
        self._status = value
        self._status_code = self._status.split(None, 1)[0]
        try:
            self._status_code = int(self.status_code)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

then use that class as the `response_class` attribute on your `Flask()` object:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(...)
app.response_object = ResponseWithSubstatus
```

The above changes remove the requirement that `status_code` is an integer.

Note that it may still be possible for your WSGI server to choke on this! Different WSGI servers may handle a non-conformant status line better or worse.

Comment: This is looking promising. Thank you.

Comment: @sisanared: note that I currently can't find any evidence that IIS actually sets the sub-status code *in the HTTP response status line*. It looks like it is only an internal code used to log and to select more detailed error messages. The status code would still be `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized`. Are you **sure** that you need to set this in the status line?

Comment: @MartijnPieters https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/sending-status-as-401-1.73739/ "Please note that there is no such thing as a 401.1 when it comes to the HTTP
headers themselves. (Watch using a network sniffer to confirm for
yourself).

When you see a 401.1 in IE, what's really happening is that IIS is sending
down a HTTP/401 error code in that HTTP Result, but the body text provides
the additional information you're seeing that claims it's really a 401.1"

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk: thanks for the confirmation! The source being Microsoft themselves is very helpful there.